# Изменить запрос на получение фото из Instagram

Tags: php, instagram

Получал фото из Instagram вот так:

```
$instagram = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/{{ name }}/?__a=1');
```

Но вчера заметил, что это перестало работать.
Сейчас получаю:

> Access to www.instagram.com was denied.You don't have authorization to view this page.

Возможно ли добавить разрешения в текущий запрос?

Допустим вот так:

```
https://www.instagram.com/{{ name }}/?__a=1&access_token=token
```

Чтобы не менять текущий вывод в шаблоне.